# Validate some HTML ( non strict ) from C#?

Tags: c#, html, validation

Any thoughts on a library (.NET / C# ) to use to validate a HTML that the user uploads to my website via upload ? It doesn't have to be super strict validation, just something to say if the document uploaded is a decent HTML or not...

Comment: HtmlAgilityPack seems to be the defecto library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the HtmlAgilityPack available through nuget

Answer (score 1):

Just run htmltidy using `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()`, and count the errors.